# JNI JVM in c++ not able to use allotted heap memory

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

```
i am calling java code in c++ using jni ,i alloted 60GB as max heap memory ,but while running its using less memory because of that its taking much time .
```

I am using windows7 OS ,VS2008.

same thing i run java using console ,it is using allottted memory ,and doing fastly
can u please help me out of this.

Updated Explanation:

We have a memory intensive java application which we tried in following two ways.

1.from a c++ application using JNI.

2.executed directly through command prompt.

in both the cases we alloted heap memory size for jvm of 60GB . we found the following difference between the above two method of execution.

1.c++ application using JNI reaches up to 40GB memory.(slow execution)

2.executed through command prompt reaches around 60GB memory.(fast execution)

what may be the reason for the difference in memory usage??.

### jVM initialisation:

```
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
 JavaVMOption options[3];

 options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=c:\\Application\\bin-7.0\\morpher\\app.jar;";
 options[1].optionString = "-Xms1024m";
 options[2].optionString = "-Xmx50000m";

 vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
 vm_args.nOptions = 3;
 vm_args.options = options;
 vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;
 JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(&vm_args);
 int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to answer your question phrased the way it is but I can tell you that.

- you can allocate heap very fast, 400+ MB of very small objects per second. Much faster for large objects.
- you may find that increasing you eden size increases the rate you can allocate objects by reducing the number GCs triggered.
- what is likely to be slowing you down is heap collections.  I suggest increasing your eden size but also reducing your heap by placing the bulk of your data in native memory with ByteBuffers and memory mapped files.
- you can attach 500 GB of memory mapped files in a few seconds or less.
- If you are creating hundreds or millions of objects it is worth reconsidering your design to reduce the number of objects e.g. using a column based table instead of a row based table. (You might only have dozens of columns, but millions of rows and creating dozens of arrays is faster than creating millions of objects)

Comment: i've edited my original post please see the Updated Explanation: thanks for your reply.

Comment: AFAIK, When you start Java from C++ it doesn't start with the same default options as it does from the command line.  I suspect there are options you are missing which have to be provided to give full performance.  As starting the JVM from C++ always seamed more trouble than it was worth, I only use the command line start.

Comment: i've posted the jvm initialization code. am i missing something?.

Comment: these are the settings i am using am i missing anything ? Thanks for your reply